# 3 argument minimum comparison issue c++

Tags: c++

I am attempting to find the minimum cost path of an array. The code works when restricted to moving either down or to the right, but not diagonally.

Issue:

```
return min(findMinCost( cost, m - 1, n), 
           findMinCost(cost, m, n - 1), 
           findMinCost(cost, m - 1, n - 1)) + cost[m - 1][n - 1];
```

I added the third argument for a diagonal movement, however it seems I cannot compare 3 arguments using min. What would be the easiest way to make this comparison?
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In c++ `min` can take 2 arguments. You should calculate the min like this,

```
return min(
          min(findMinCost( cost, m - 1, n), 
              findMinCost(cost, m, n - 1)), 
              findMinCost(cost, m - 1, n - 1)) + cost[m - 1][n - 1];
```

That way, you will at first find the minimum between `findMinCost( cost, m - 1, n)` and `findMinCost(cost, m, n - 1)`. And then find the minimum of the first minimum and `findMinCost(cost, m - 1, n - 1)`. Its like if you want to find minimum of `a,b,c`,

```
int x = min(a, b);
int min = min(x, c);
```

Comment: Actually, [min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) can take a whole list of values and not just two.

Comment: Yes, if we pass a list of values. But we can not pass more than 2 params for min function. I mean `min(integerList, compFunc)` is possible. But `min(a,b,c,d,...)` is not possible without overloading the min function. If I am missing something feel free to correct me. Thank you.

Comment: @sabbir.alam [`std::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) (4) specifically.

Comment: Yes, but still you will be able to pass 2 parameters in the function. One of them is a list of numbers. But you can not pass more than 2 parameters, right?

Comment: The first paramter can be an initializer list. So your above example can be written as `std::min({a, b, c, d})` - that's perfectly fine, the comparator is optional.

Comment: Yes, i understand your answer. But {1,2,3,4} still count as one parameter to the min function. In the question above he is not passing a integer list. He is passing 3 different integer as prams. Which is not possible.